# QVideoWidget не хочет воспроизводить видео, когда приложение скомпилировано pyinstaller'ом. PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Когда запускаешь приложение с IDE, всё воспроизводится нормально. Но если скомпилировать pyinstaller'ом, то значки кодеков быстро появляются и исчезают.

Команда такая:
`pyinstaller main.py form.py --onefile -w --noupx`

Вывод:

```
(venv) C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer>pyinstaller main.py form.py --onefile -w --noupx >> ass.txt
151 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
151 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
151 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
155 INFO: wrote C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\main.spec
267 INFO: UPX is available.
271 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\xDololow\\Desktop\\PyPlayer',
 'C:\\Users\\xDololow\\Desktop\\PyPlayer',
 'C:\\Users\\xDololow\\Desktop\\PyPlayer']
271 INFO: checking Analysis
275 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
275 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
287 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
291 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7317 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7361 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\xdololow\desktop\pyplayer\venv\scripts\python.exe
7385 INFO: Caching module hooks...
7429 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\main.py
7657 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\form.py
7669 INFO: Loading module hooks...
7673 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7829 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
7837 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
8141 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
8141 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
9473 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
12382 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtMultimedia.py"...
15575 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtNetwork.py"...
17679 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
20736 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
21268 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
21268 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
21276 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
21284 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
33103 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\users\xdololow\desktop\pyplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\audio\qtaudio_wasapi.dll
33827 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\users\xdololow\desktop\pyplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\audio\qtaudio_wasapi.dll
57108 INFO: Looking for eggs
57108 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\xDololow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll
57108 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
57120 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\build\main\warn-main.txt
57216 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\build\main\xref-main.html
57244 INFO: checking PYZ
57244 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
57244 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
58712 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
58732 INFO: checking PKG
58732 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
58732 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
59097 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
59097 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\xdololow\\desktop\\pyplayer\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
59097 WARNING: was placed previously at
59097 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\xdololow\\desktop\\pyplayer\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
84434 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
84450 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\xdololow\desktop\pyplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
84450 INFO: checking EXE
84450 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
84450 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
84450 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\xDololow\Desktop\PyPlayer\dist\main.exe
84530 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Часть кода:

```py
import fix_qt_import_error
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QTime, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence, QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QShortcut)
from form import Ui_MainWindow
import qdarkstyle
import sys


class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.widescreen = True
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setFixedSize(842, 668)

        #style
        app.setStyle("Fusion")

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.StreamPlayback)
        self.mediaPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.printMediaData)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.ui.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.ui.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.ui.openButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

        self.ui.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.ui.positionSlider.setSingleStep(2)
        self.ui.positionSlider.setPageStep(20)
        self.ui.positionSlider.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.ui.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)
        self.ui.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.handleLabel)
        self.ui.volumeSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeVolume)
        self.ui.fullscreenButton.clicked.connect(self.handleFullscreen)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        self.ui.playerWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.handleLabel)

        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

        #hot keys
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence.FullScreen, self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.handleFullscreen)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+O"), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.openFile)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence.Cancel, self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.handleQuit)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Space), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.play)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Up), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.volumeUp)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Down), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.volumeDown)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Right), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.forwardSlider)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Left), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.backSlider)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ShiftModifier + Qt.Key_Right), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.forwardSlider10)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ShiftModifier + Qt.Key_Left), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.backSlider10)
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("B"), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.changeStyle)


    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Открыть медиа файл",
                QDir.homePath(), "Медиа (*.webm *.mp4 *.ts *.avi *.mpeg *.mpg *.mkv *.VOB *.m4v *.3gp *.mp3 *.m4a *.wav *.ogg *.flac *.m3u *.m3u8)")

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.ui.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.filenameLabel.setText(fileName[fileName.rfind("/")+1:])
            if fileName[fileName.rfind(".")+1:] in ["mp3", "m4a", "wav", "ogg", "flac"]:
                self.ui.playerWidget.hide()
                self.setFixedSize(842, 196)
                self.ui.widget.move(0, 0)
                self.ui.fullscreenButton.setEnabled(False)
            else:
                self.ui.playerWidget.show()
                self.setFixedSize(842, 668)
                self.ui.widget.move(0, 459)
                self.ui.fullscreenButton.setEnabled(True)

    def changeStyle(self):
        if app.styleSheet() != '':
            app.setStyleSheet('')
        else:
            app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Трудно проверить то, о чем вы говорите, т.к. пример предоставлен не рабочий.
Обратите внимание на строки протокола: `33103 WARNING:` и `33827 WARNING:`.
Может `qtaudio_wasapi.dll` и `qtaudio_wasapi.dll` надо туда положить?

Comment: Пофиксил WARNINGи и всё равно не воспроизводит.

Comment: Публикуйте минимальный рабочий пример, будем посмотреть .

Comment: Решил проблему переименовыванием файла с main.py в main1.py 